# How can I run a PowerShell script in GitLab pipeline?

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am running a pipeline job on a Windows VM, with default executor as **shell**. In this job, I wish to run a powershell script, which is located in a directory called CICD, by the following lines:

```
- powershell .\CICD\build_script.ps1 x86 $PROJECT_PATH
- .\CICD\build_script.ps1 x86 $PROJECT_PATH
- '.\CICD\build_script.ps1 x86 $PROJECT_PATH'
```

The script has 2 arguments: x86 and $PROJECT_PATH.
Everytime I try to run one of these commands, I get this error:

```
.\CICD\build_script.ps1 : The term '.\CICD\build_script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\CICD\build_script.ps1 x86 C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\BRmNra1o\0\mihnea ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\CICD\build_script.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there a proper way to run this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `/` instead of a `\`:

```
- cd CICD
- ./build_script.ps1 x86 $PROJECT_PATH
```